# Workaround for xlwings UDFs in Excel with cl commands blocked?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I have been attempting to import UDFs into an Excel workbook using xlwings (using the simple UDF given in the xlwings docs https://docs.xlwings.org/en/latest/udfs.html#udfs). This process is being blocked by a cloud security application called Carbon Black. Has anybody found a workaround for using xlwings UDFs when Excel cannot create child processes?[image: xlwings error]

Comment: Custom functions are based on Office.js add-in, i.e., do not have VBA/dll-based dependecies (they also get rid of the local Python installation): https://docs.xlwings.org/en/latest/pro/server/officejs_custom_functions.html